# Continuity of a function on $\Bbb R^2$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, continuity

> Function $f(x,y)$ is defined in a neighborhood of $(0,0)$. Then
>
> 1. if for any t function $g(x) = f(x,tx)$ is continuous at $0$, then $f$ is continuous at $(0,0)$.
> 2. if $f$ is continuous at $(0,0)$, then $xy \cdot f(x,y)$ is differentiable at $(0,0)$.
> 3. if $\sin f(x,y)$ is continuous at $(0,0)$, then $f$ is continuous at $(0,0)$.

Please, help me to solve this. I know that the second choice is correct.

Comment: so what exactly do you want to do? any thoughts? why should $2)$ be true?

Comment: 2 is true because the answer tells me so

Comment: and why could it be true? for example, if you suspect $1)$ not to be true, counter examples would be a good way to prove that

Comment: I've no idea, unfortunately

Comment: @Brat Surely there are some examples on how to prove a function isn't continuous. Some of the standard examples will also be examples for 1. For 3., think in one variable, consider for instance $f(0)=\pi$ and $f(u)=0$, if $u\neq 0$. Finally to prove 2 use the definition of differentiability.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Is wrong. Consider $$\begin{array}{l|rcl}
   f : & \mathbb R^2 & \longrightarrow & \mathbb R \\
       & (x,y) & \longmapsto & \frac{x^2 y}{x^4+y^2} \text{ for } (x,y) \neq (0,0) \\
   & (0,0) & \longmapsto & 0 \end{array}$$ You have $$f(x,tx)=\frac{x^2 tx}{x^4+t^2x^2}=\frac{tx}{x^2+t^2} $$ Which tends to $0$ for all $t \in \mathbb R$. However $\lim\limits_{x \to 0} f(x,x^2) = \frac{1}{2}$
2. Is true. Suppose that $\lim\limits_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} f(x,y) =a$ then you have $$\vert xyf(x,y) - axy \vert \le \vert xy \vert \vert f(x,y)-a \vert \le \frac{\Vert (x,y) \Vert^2_2}{2} \vert f(x,y) -a\vert$$ The map $$(x,y) \mapsto axy$$ is differentiable at $(0,0)$ and $$\frac{\Vert (x,y) \Vert^2_2}{2} \vert f(x,y) -a\vert = o(\Vert (x,y) \Vert_2)$$ Hence $xy f(x,y)$ is differentiable at $(0,0)$ and the derivative is the one of $(x,y) \mapsto axy$, i.e. the always vanishing linear map.
3. Is wrong. Consider $$\begin{array}{l|rcl}
   f : & \mathbb R^2 & \longrightarrow & \mathbb R \\
       & (x,y) & \longmapsto & 0 \text{ for } x \neq y \\
   & (x,y) & \longmapsto & 2 \pi \text{ for } x = y \end{array}$$

Comment: hi, I think your first counter example does not work, here is why: if you put $g(x)=f(x,tx)=\frac{x^2(1-t^2)}{x^2(1+t^2)}$ which is clearly not continuous $\forall t$ in the point $(0,0)$

Comment: For $t$ fixed $f(x,tx)$ IS continuous as $x \to 0$.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom just a question, wouldn't $f(x,y) = \frac{x^4}{x^2 + y^2}$ be continuous at $(0,0)$?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom but you cannot set $g(x)=f(x,x^2)$ since $t$ is arbitrary but fixed, or am I completely wrong here?!

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net for a fixed $t$, $x \mapsto f(x,tx)$ is *only* continuous if $\frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2} = 0$

Comment: @Omnomnomnom I second your opinion with the first counterexample but I have to disagree with yours, since $f$ is continuous, let's choose your path to zero with$\lim_{x\to 0} (x,x^2)$, so $\lim_{x\to 0} f(x,x^2)=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{x^4}{x^2+x^4}=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{1}{x^{-2}+1}=0$ as we need to for continuity under the same defnition, please correct me if you think I am wrong

Comment: @user190080 my mistake

Comment: Consider the function
$$
f(x,y) = \frac{x + y^2}{x}
$$
and the path $g(y) = f(y^2,y)$

Comment: @Omnomnomnom I tried to contact you through the chat, didn't work, but what I wrote was crap anyway. This example looks really good, $f(0,0)=1$, and this should indeed work!